# Prettier: invalid configuration file even though the file is straight from the docs

Tags: prettier, prettier-vscode

So I tried installing the prettier today, I followed the instructions straight from the [docs.](https://prettier.io/docs/en/install.html)

```
npm install --save-dev --save-exact prettier
echo {}> .prettierrc.json
```

then I create a .prettierignore and copy-pasted what's written in my .gitignore in there. Meanwhile, this is what I wrote in the .prettierrc.json:

```
{
   "singleQuote": true
}
```

Now when I run the prettier in the command line:

```
npx prettier --write src/index.js
```

I get this error:

```
PS C:\file-directory> npx prettier --write src/index.js
[error] Invalid configuration file `src\index.js`: JSON Error in C:\file-directory\.prettierrc.json:
[error]
[error] > 1 | ��{
[error]     | ^
[error]   2 |
[error]   3 |    "singleQuote": true
[error]   4 |
[error]
[error] Unexpected token "�" (0xFFFD) in JSON at position 0 while parsing near "��{\u0000\r\u0000\n\u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000\"\u0000s\u0000i\u0000..."
[error]
[error] > 1 | ��{
[error]     | ^
[error]   2 |
[error]   3 |    "singleQuote": true
[error]   4 |
[error]
```

My json file is not showing any errors in vscode... I have the prettier extension disabled since I want to try it out in the CLI but if I enabled it, it will not work, it shows the same error if I click the "Prettier" in the bottom-right of the vscode so this is definitely a config file problem...

Comment: Ran into the same issue. Deleted the .prettierrc.json then made the file through the Visual Studio IDE, and everything worked. Must not work when making the file through the command line?

Comment: You should add this as an answer.

Comment: I agree, this worked for me..., please post this as answer @mthrasher33

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Answered by mthrasher33 in the comment section:

> Ran into the same issue. Deleted the .prettierrc.json then made the
> file through the Visual Studio IDE, and everything worked. Must not
> work when making the file through the command line?

Comment: you are my hero

Answer (score 9):

The configuration file that I created through the command "echo .prettierrc.json" created with file format UTF16 and that caused an error while trying to run it. So I changed the file format physically to be of format UTF8 and it works fine.

Comment: Thank you, bugs like this are absurdly hard to find especially since vscode was opening it as utf8

Answer (score 1):

Changing the UTF16 to UTF8 using Notepad++ worked well for me.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is still facing this annoying problem, If your configuration file ends with `.js`, please check the syntax. You may have forgotten a comma or made any other misspellings.

I had this problem after I had updated my prettier configuration file, I forgot a comma and VScode didn't highlight any syntax errors. Fortunately, I noticed this after some tries.

Answer (score 0):

Add prettierrc file extension in the package.json command:

```
    "prettier-format": "prettier --config .prettierrc.js 'src/**/*.ts' --write"
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose to rename file from `.js` to `.cjs`.

Comment: Please, [edit] and try for [answer], describe the effect of what you propose and explain why it helps to solve the problem. Consider taking the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

try running this command "npx prettier --write ." after manually creating prettier file

Comment: You need that tried before you can identify a solution? Or can you [edit] and provide an answer according to [answer] right now?