# Getting "Invalid prettier configuration file detected" error

Tags: visual-studio-code, lint, prettier

I am getting following errors whenever I am trying to format my `.ts` or `.html` file using `alt + shift + f`

[image]

I have set prettier as the default formatter.

I have checked all the possible solutions from these posts.

[Prettier: invalid configuration file even though the file is straight from the docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70387394/prettier-invalid-configuration-file-even-though-the-file-is-straight-from-the-d)

[prettier configuration error, prettier not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64970988/prettier-configuration-error-prettier-not-working)

https://linuxpip.org/vscode-prettier-not-working/

https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode/issues/1292

Also, I confirmed that the file `prettier.config.js` with following content does exist in my root directory

```
module.exports = {
  tabWidth: 2,
  semi: true,
  singleQuote: true,
  bracketSpacing: true,
  printWidth: 100,
  endOfLine: 'auto',
  trailingComma: 'all',
};
```

Also, I have set the prettier as default formatter in my `settings.json` file

[image]

The problem is that is not giving any information of what the problem is with the config file.

And it says that `See log for details.` but I am not sure where to look for the logs

Any help?

Comment: I encountered this errors. Did you solve the errors?